# Kubernetes logs shows healthy app, but ReadinessProbe fails

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes

## My goal

To deploy a React app to a Kubernetes cluster and access it from my web browser.

### The setup

I'm packaging a React app into a Docker container. Inside the Docker container, I'm running `npm build` then serving the static files using the npm package `serve`.

Then, using Helm, I pull the Docker image and deploy it to an EKS Cluster. At this point, my logs show that the container is `Running` and `Alive` (see logs below).

#### The problem

On the EKS Cluster, there is an Ingress which directs inbound traffic to the Service (aka, my Docker Container). Yet, when I point my browser to the Host URL, I receive a 503 error.

My understanding is that the traffic flows like this:

```
(Inbound traffic) -> ingress.example.com:80 -> (docker container:8080)
```

I've triple checked the port mappings on my manifest.yaml, but I'm completely lost.

### My logs

The Kubernetes Log seem to show that the deployment is alive...

```
Invoked Entrypoint..
generating cert and key for your application...
> web-app-2@0.1.0 start:prod /
> HOST=0.0.0.0 serve -s build -l 8080
INFO  Accepting connections at http://localhost:8080
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:12 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 GET /health
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:12 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 Returned 200 in 18 ms
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:17 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 GET /health
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:17 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 GET /health
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:17 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 Returned 200 in 3 ms
HTTP  4/26/2023 7:56:17 PM 2600:1f18:664d:c501:48e1:f54e:7ced:a524 Returned 200 in 3 ms
// and so on...
```

But running `kubectl describe` shows that the readiness probe fails, despite the `/health` endpoint returning `200 OK`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  41m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned NAMESPACE/health-react-react-webapp-cbdbc576c-wjk7p to ip-123-123-123-123.ec2.internal
  Normal   Pulling    41m                kubelet            Pulling image IMAGE_NAME
  Normal   Pulled     41m                kubelet            Successfully pulled image IMAGE_NAME in 153.428514ms
  Normal   Created    41m                kubelet            Created container react-webapp
  Normal   Started    41m                kubelet            Started container react-webapp
  Warning  Unhealthy  41m (x2 over 41m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://[IPV6_ADDRESS]:8080/health": dial tcp [IPV6_ADDRESS]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

My `manifest.yaml` (generated by `helm install --debug`)

```yaml
NAME: health-react
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Apr 26 16:30:28 2023
NAMESPACE: REDACTED
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1

MANIFEST:
---
# Source: react-webapp/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: health-react-react-webapp
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: react-webapp-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: react-webapp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: health-react
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
---
# Source: react-webapp/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: health-react-react-webapp
  namespace: NAMESPACE
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: react-webapp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: health-react
    type: ClusterIP
---
# Source: react-webapp/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: health-react-react-webapp
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: react-webapp-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: react-webapp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: health-react
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: react-webapp
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: health-react
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: react-webapp
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: health-react
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ricky-cred
      serviceAccountName: health-react-react-webapp
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: react-webapp
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "REDACTED"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
          resources:
            {}
---
# Source: react-webapp/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: health-react-react-webapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  namespace: NAMESPACE
spec:
  ingressClassName: 
  rules:
    - host: ingress.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /virtualization-web(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: health-react-react-webapp
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing two different issues so let's tackle them one after another.

### Issue 1: Unhealthy Pods

As you have figured from the logs, your pod is actually ok. What you see in the output of `describe` shows you the results of all past probes, so if one failed, you will see that there, especially if it's a recent one. So in your case, you can see that two probes failed over the last 41m. This is not the current state of your pod. Here's an example where my pod had issues in the past but is fine now:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------          ----                  ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling         4h12m (x15 over 18h)  kubelet  Pulling image "quay.io/rira12621/single-arch-amd64"
  Normal   Created         4h12m (x15 over 18h)  kubelet  Created container single-wrong-arch
  Normal   Started         4h12m (x15 over 18h)  kubelet  Started container single-wrong-arch
  Normal   Pulled          4h12m                 kubelet  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/rira12621/single-arch-amd64" in 1.696594293s (1.696604668s including waiting)
  Warning  FailedMount     83s                   kubelet  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-qcgg7" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
  Normal   SandboxChanged  82s                   kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling         81s                   kubelet  Pulling image "quay.io/rira12621/single-arch-amd64"
  Normal   Pulled          79s                   kubelet  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/rira12621/single-arch-amd64" in 2.186910459s (2.18691371s including waiting)
  Normal   Created         79s                   kubelet  Created container single-wrong-arch
  Normal   Started         79s                   kubelet  Started container single-wrong-arch
```

And a little further up in the output the current state:

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
```

### Issue 2: Connecting fails

You need to double check on your config here. It's a bit of a mix and match.

Unless I've read your description wrong, then the port spec for your pod is wrong:

```
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
```

Your app is listening for regular traffic on 8080 as well and not 80, according to your schematic diagram.